# Disable ajax for add to cart button in single product page / Wordpress / Woocommerce

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce

I am developing an eCommerce website using wordpress, cartify theme, woocommerce 3.0.3.

I would like to redirect after to cart or checkout after clicking the buy now product.

[Here you can see the page](https://1001secretdeals.com/products/april-birthstone-ring-sterling-silver-jewelry/)

```
**Add to cart behaviour**

✔︎ Redirect to the cart page after successful addition
(Unchecked) Enable AJAX add to cart buttons on archives
```

I activated redirect to cart after add to cart click and left in the woo commerce options but it seems to still using ajax.

```
**WooCommerce System status**

MySQL version: 5.5.51 - We recommend a minimum MySQL version of 5.6.
(THE HOST PROVIDER DOESN'T ALLOW ME TO UPGRADE)

WC pages
My account:      Page does not contain the shortcode.

cartify/woocommerce/single-product/product-image.php version 2.6.3 is out of date. The core version is 3.0.2, 
cartify/woocommerce/single-product/product-thumbnails.php version 2.6.3 is out of date. The core version is 3.0.2,
This two really mess my site when I update them.
```

Any suggestions, please?

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: you want that if the user clicks on add to cart it will redirect the customer to the checkout page ? or you want to redirect customer from listing page to check out or only single page to checkout?

Answer (score 1):

SO here I am going to explain three steps

**Step 1** if you want customer to redirect after adding to cart to checkout then add below code to the functions.php

```
function my_custom_add_to_cart_redirect( $url ) {

  $url = WC()->cart->get_checkout_url();
  // $url = wc_get_checkout_url(); // since WC 2.5.0

  return $url;

  }
  add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 'my_custom_add_to_cart_redirect' );
```

**Step 2** if you want customer to redirect to the cart page after add to cart the following image link showing you can do this from admin end

http://prntscr.com/ewo99j

**Step 3** if from admin end it's not redirecting the customer to the cart page then add following code to your functions.PHP

```
 function custom_add_to_cart_redirect() { 
  return 'http://localhost:8080/wordpress2/cart/'; 
  }
  add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 'custom_add_to_cart_redirect' );
```

replace this URL http://localhost:8080/wordpress2/cart/ with your cart page URL 
hope it will work for you

Thanks

Comment: first, clear me what you want exactly from above steps

Comment: Thank you again. I want either 1 or 2. Before woocommerce 3.0.0 Step 2 was working but know it only use ajax to add to cart and it's not redirecting. I've installed a second button and it is not working neither... you can check my page...

Answer (score 0):

You can use this jquery in your theme.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $(".add_to_cart_button").removeClass("ajax_add_to_cart")
 });
```

Then you can use this code in your functions.php for redirect into the checkout page:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect','themeprefix_add_to_cart_redirect');
function themeprefix_add_to_cart_redirect() {
     global $woocommerce;
     $checkout_url = $woocommerce->cart->get_checkout_url();
     return $checkout_url;
}
```